RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
I am trying to implement CUDA for this graph neural network model "https://github.com/VincLee8188/GMAN-PyTorch" to use the nvidia GPU to be able to speed up the process since with the CPU it takes about 10 hours, all this I am using kaggle and I wanted to be able to use their GPU. I started to implement it but I get this error as soon as the training model is started. I am inserting below the main, model and train.
edit2: I've updated the code now and after starting the main anyway the same problem comes out, however it comes out right after finishing the training so it's already a step forward..., I put in output main the new output
Output main:
Training batch: 2270/2279 in epoch:0, training batch loss:20.8169
Training batch: 2275/2279 in epoch:0, training batch loss:27.4643
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\palli\OneDrive\Desktop\GMAN-GPU FUNZIONANTE\GMAN-PyTorch-master\main2.py", line 97, in <module>
    loss_train, loss_val, val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape = train(model, args, log, loss_criterion, optimizer, scheduler, device)
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\palli\OneDrive\Desktop\GMAN-GPU FUNZIONANTE\GMAN-PyTorch-master\model\train.py", line 102, in train
    val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape = metric(valPred, valY)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\palli\OneDrive\Desktop\GMAN-GPU FUNZIONANTE\GMAN-PyTorch-master\utils\utils_.py", line 19, in metric
    mae = torch.abs(torch.sub(pred, label)).type(torch.float32)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!

Main:
import argparse
import time
from typing_extensions import Self
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import wandb
import os  

from utils.utils_ import log_string, plot_train_val_loss
from utils.utils_ import count_parameters, load_data

from model.model_ import GMAN
from model.train import train
from model.test import test

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--time_slot', type=int, default=5,
                    help='a time step is 5 mins')
parser.add_argument('--num_his', type=int, default=12,
                    help='history steps')
parser.add_argument('--num_pred', type=int, default=12,
                    help='prediction steps')
parser.add_argument('--L', type=int, default=1,
                    help='number of STAtt Blocks')
parser.add_argument('--K', type=int, default=8,
                    help='number of attention heads')
parser.add_argument('--d', type=int, default=8,
                    help='dims of each head attention outputs')
parser.add_argument('--train_ratio', type=float, default=0.7,
                    help='training set [default : 0.7]')
parser.add_argument('--val_ratio', type=float, default=0.1,
                    help='validation set [default : 0.1]')
parser.add_argument('--test_ratio', type=float, default=0.2,
                    help='testing set [default : 0.2]')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=8, # 32
                    help='batch size')
parser.add_argument('--max_epoch', type=int, default=1,
                    help='epoch to run')
parser.add_argument('--patience', type=int, default=10,
                    help='patience for early stop')
parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.001,
                    help='initial learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--decay_epoch', type=int, default=10,
                    help='decay epoch')
parser.add_argument('--traffic_file', default='/kaggle/working/GMAN/data/pems-bay.h5',
                    help='traffic file')
parser.add_argument('--SE_file', default='/kaggle/working/GMAN/data/SE(PeMS).txt',
                    help='spatial embedding file')
parser.add_argument('--model_file', default='/kaggle/working/GMAN/data/GMAN.pkl',
                    help='save the model to disk')
parser.add_argument('--log_file', default='/kaggle/working/GMAN/data/log',
                    help='log file')
args = parser.parse_args()
log = open(args.log_file, 'w')
log_string(log, str(args)[10: -1])
T = 24 * 60 // args.time_slot  # Number of time steps in one day

#modified for GPU utilization
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Set up wandb with the API key
os.environ['WANDB_API_KEY'] = '1a020476226c8b2a0f57dd39277650363d35253b'  
wandb.login()

# Wandb
wandb.init(project="new_project_name", entity="epdragon-universit-degli-studi-di-milano-bicocca")  
wandb.config.update(args)

# load data
log_string(log, 'loading data...')
(trainX, trainTE, trainY, valX, valTE, valY, testX, testTE,
 testY, SE, mean, std) = load_data(args)
log_string(log, f'trainX: {trainX.shape}\t\t trainY: {trainY.shape}')
log_string(log, f'valX:   {valX.shape}\t\tvalY:   {valY.shape}')
log_string(log, f'testX:   {testX.shape}\t\ttestY:   {testY.shape}')
log_string(log, f'mean:   {mean:.4f}\t\tstd:   {std:.4f}')
log_string(log, 'data loaded!')
del trainX, trainTE, valX, valTE, testX, testTE, mean, std
# build model
log_string(log, 'compiling model...')

model = GMAN(SE, args, bn_decay=0.1)
loss_criterion = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), args.learning_rate)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                      step_size=args.decay_epoch,
                                      gamma=0.9)
parameters = count_parameters(model)
log_string(log, 'trainable parameters: {:,}'.format(parameters))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    loss_train, loss_val, val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape = train(model, args, log, loss_criterion, optimizer, scheduler, device)
    loss_val = [validation.detach().cpu().numpy() for validation in loss_val]
    wandb.log({
        "loss_train": loss_train,
        "loss_val": loss_val,
        "val_mae": val_mae, 
        "val_rmse": val_rmse, 
        "val_mape": val_mape
        })
    plot_train_val_loss(loss_train, loss_val, 'figure/train_val_loss.png')
    trainPred, valPred, testPred = test(args, log, device)
    end = time.time()
    log_string(log, 'total time: %.1fmin' % ((end - start) / 60))
    log.close()

    trainPred_ = trainPred.reshape(-1, trainY.shape[-1])
    trainY_ = trainY.reshape(-1, trainY.shape[-1])
    valPred_ = valPred.reshape(-1, valY.shape[-1])
    valY_ = valY.reshape(-1, valY.shape[-1])
    testPred_ = testPred.reshape(-1, testY.shape[-1])
    testY_ = testY.reshape(-1, testY.shape[-1])

    # Save training, validation and testing datas to disk
    l = [trainPred_, trainY_, valPred_, valY_, testPred_, testY_]

    print("Saving predictions...")
    name = ['trainPred', 'trainY', 'valPred', 'valY', 'testPred', 'testY']
    for i, data in enumerate(l):
        np.savetxt('./figure/' + name[i] + '.txt', data.detach().cpu().numpy(), fmt='%s')

Train:
import time
import datetime
from utils.utils_ import log_string
from model.model_ import *
from utils.utils_ import load_data
from utils.utils_ import metric
import numpy as np

def train(model, args, log, loss_criterion, optimizer, scheduler,device):

    (trainX, trainTE, trainY, valX, valTE, valY, testX, testTE,
     testY, SE, mean, std) = load_data(args)

    # GPU Util
    #trainX = trainX.to(device)
    #trainTE = trainTE.to(device)
    #trainY = trainY.to(device)
    #valX = valX.to(device)
    #valTE = valTE.to(device)
    #valY = valY.to(device)
    #testX = testX.to(device)
    #testTE = testTE.to(device)
    #testY = testY.to(device)
    #SE = SE.to(device)
    #mean = mean.to(device)
    #std = std.to(device)

    #GPU util
    model.to(device)

    num_train, _, num_vertex = trainX.shape
    log_string(log, '**** training model ****')
    num_val = valX.shape[0]
    train_num_batch = math.ceil(num_train / args.batch_size)
    val_num_batch = math.ceil(num_val / args.batch_size)

    wait = 0
    val_loss_min = float('inf')
    best_model_wts = None
    train_total_loss = []
    val_total_loss = []

    # Train & validation
    for epoch in range(args.max_epoch):
        if wait >= args.patience:
            log_string(log, f'early stop at epoch: {epoch:04d}')
            break
        # shuffle
        permutation = torch.randperm(num_train)
        trainX = trainX[permutation]
        trainTE = trainTE[permutation]
        trainY = trainY[permutation]
        # train
        start_train = time.time()
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0
        for batch_idx in range(train_num_batch):
            start_idx = batch_idx * args.batch_size
            end_idx = min(num_train, (batch_idx + 1) * args.batch_size)
            X = trainX[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            TE = trainTE[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            label = trainY[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            pred = model(X, TE)
            pred = pred * std + mean
            loss_batch = loss_criterion(pred, label)
            train_loss += float(loss_batch) * (end_idx - start_idx)
            loss_batch.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                torch.cuda.empty_cache()
            if (batch_idx+1) % 5 == 0:
                print(f'Training batch: {batch_idx+1}/{train_num_batch} in epoch:{epoch}, training batch loss:{loss_batch:.4f}')
            del X, TE, label, pred, loss_batch
        train_loss /= num_train
        train_total_loss.append(train_loss)
        end_train = time.time()

        # val loss
        start_val = time.time()
        val_loss = 0
        model.eval()
        valPred = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch_idx in range(val_num_batch):
                start_idx = batch_idx * args.batch_size
                end_idx = min(num_val, (batch_idx + 1) * args.batch_size)
                X = valX[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
                TE = valTE[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
                label = valY[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
                pred = model(X, TE)
                pred = pred * std + mean
                loss_batch = loss_criterion(pred, label)
                val_loss += loss_batch * (end_idx - start_idx)
                valPred.append(pred.detach().clone())
                del X, TE, label, pred, loss_batch
        val_loss /= num_val
        val_total_loss.append(val_loss)
        valPred = [vp.detach().cpu().numpy() for vp in valPred]
        valPred = torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(valPred, axis=0)).to(device)
        valPred = valPred * std + mean
        val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape = metric(valPred, valY)
        end_val = time.time()
        
        log_string(
            log,
            '%s | epoch: %04d/%d, training time: %.1fs, inference time: %.1fs' %
            (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), epoch + 1,
             args.max_epoch, end_train - start_train, end_val - start_val))
        log_string(
            log, f'train loss: {train_loss:.4f}, val_loss: {val_loss:.4f}, mae: {val_mae:.4f}, rmse: {val_rmse:.4f}, mape: {val_mape:.4f}')
        if val_loss <= val_loss_min:
            log_string(
                log,
                f'val loss decrease from {val_loss_min:.4f} to {val_loss:.4f}, saving model to {args.model_file}')
            wait = 0
            val_loss_min = val_loss
            best_model_wts = model.state_dict()
        else:
            wait += 1
        scheduler.step()

    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    torch.save(model, args.model_file)
    log_string(log, f'Training and validation are completed, and model has been stored as {args.model_file}')
    return train_total_loss, val_total_loss, val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape


Model:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class conv2d_(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dims, output_dims, kernel_size, stride=(1, 1),
                 padding='SAME', use_bias=True, activation=F.relu,
                 bn_decay=None):
        super(conv2d_, self).__init__()
        self.activation = activation
        if padding == 'SAME':
            self.padding_size = math.ceil(kernel_size)
        else:
            self.padding_size = [0, 0]
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(input_dims, output_dims, kernel_size, stride=stride,
                              padding=0, bias=use_bias)
        self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm2d(output_dims, momentum=bn_decay)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv.weight)

        if use_bias:
            torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.conv.bias)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(device)
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)
        x = F.pad(x, ([self.padding_size[1], self.padding_size[1], self.padding_size[0], self.padding_size[0]]))
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.batch_norm(x)
        if self.activation is not None:
            x = F.relu_(x)
        return x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)


class FC(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dims, units, activations, bn_decay, use_bias=True):
        super(FC, self).__init__()
        if isinstance(units, int):
            units = [units]
            input_dims = [input_dims]
            activations = [activations]
        elif isinstance(units, tuple):
            units = list(units)
            input_dims = list(input_dims)
            activations = list(activations)
        assert type(units) == list
        self.convs = nn.ModuleList([conv2d_(
            input_dims=input_dim, output_dims=num_unit, kernel_size=[1, 1], stride=[1, 1],
            padding='VALID', use_bias=use_bias, activation=activation,
            bn_decay=bn_decay) for input_dim, num_unit, activation in
            zip(input_dims, units, activations)])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(device)
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv(x)
        return x


class STEmbedding(nn.Module):
    '''
    spatio-temporal embedding
    SE:     [num_vertex, D]
    TE:     [batch_size, num_his + num_pred, 2] (dayofweek, timeofday)
    T:      num of time steps in one day
    D:      output dims
    retrun: [batch_size, num_his + num_pred, num_vertex, D]
    '''

    def __init__(self, D, bn_decay):
        super(STEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.FC_se = FC(
            input_dims=[D, D], units=[D, D], activations=[F.relu, None],
            bn_decay=bn_decay)

        self.FC_te = FC(
            input_dims=[295, D], units=[D, D], activations=[F.relu, None],
            bn_decay=bn_decay)  # input_dims = time step per day + days per week=288+7=295

    def forward(self, SE, TE, T=288):
        # spatial embedding
        SE = SE.to(device)
        SE = SE.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
        SE = self.FC_se(SE)
        
        # temporal embedding
        TE = TE.to(device)
        dayofweek = torch.empty(TE.shape[0], TE.shape[1], 7)
        timeofday = torch.empty(TE.shape[0], TE.shape[1], T)
        for i in range(TE.shape[0]):
            dayofweek[i] = F.one_hot(TE[..., 0][i].to(torch.int64) % 7, 7)
        for j in range(TE.shape[0]):
            timeofday[j] = F.one_hot(TE[..., 1][j].to(torch.int64) % 288, T)
        TE = torch.cat((dayofweek, timeofday), dim=-1)
        TE = TE.unsqueeze(dim=2)
        TE = self.FC_te(TE)
        del dayofweek, timeofday
        return SE + TE


class spatialAttention(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self, K, d, bn_decay):
        super(spatialAttention, self).__init__()
        D = K * d
        self.d = d
        self.K = K
        self.FC_q = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_k = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_v = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                     bn_decay=bn_decay)

    def forward(self, X, STE):
        X = X.to(device)
        STE = STE.to(device)
        batch_size = X.shape[0]
        X = torch.cat((X, STE), dim=-1)
        # [batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, K * d]
        query = self.FC_q(X)
        key = self.FC_k(X)
        value = self.FC_v(X)
        # [K * batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, d]
        query = torch.cat(torch.split(query, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        key = torch.cat(torch.split(key, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        value = torch.cat(torch.split(value, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        # [K * batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, num_vertex]
        attention = torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(2, 3))
        attention /= (self.d ** 0.5)
        attention = F.softmax(attention, dim=-1)
        # [batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, D]
        X = torch.matmul(attention, value)
        X = torch.cat(torch.split(X, batch_size, dim=0), dim=-1)  # orginal K, change to batch_size
        X = self.FC(X)
        del query, key, value, attention
        return X


class temporalAttention(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self, K, d, bn_decay, mask=True):
        super(temporalAttention, self).__init__()
        D = K * d
        self.d = d
        self.K = K
        self.mask = mask
        self.FC_q = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_k = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_v = FC(input_dims=2 * D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                     bn_decay=bn_decay)

    def forward(self, X, STE):
        X = X.to(device)
        STE = STE.to(device)
        batch_size_ = X.shape[0]
        X = torch.cat((X, STE), dim=-1)
        # [batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, K * d]
        query = self.FC_q(X)
        key = self.FC_k(X)
        value = self.FC_v(X)
        # [K * batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, d]
        query = torch.cat(torch.split(query, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        key = torch.cat(torch.split(key, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        value = torch.cat(torch.split(value, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        # query: [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_step, d]
        # key:   [K * batch_size, num_vertex, d, num_step]
        # value: [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_step, d]
        query = query.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        key = key.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
        value = value.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        # [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_step, num_step]
        attention = torch.matmul(query, key)
        attention /= (self.d ** 0.5)
        # mask attention score
        if self.mask:
            batch_size = X.shape[0]
            num_step = X.shape[1]
            num_vertex = X.shape[2]
            mask = torch.ones(num_step, num_step)
            mask = torch.tril(mask)
            mask = torch.unsqueeze(torch.unsqueeze(mask, dim=0), dim=0)
            mask = mask.repeat(self.K * batch_size, num_vertex, 1, 1)
            mask = mask.to(torch.bool)
            attention = torch.where(mask, attention, -2 ** 15 + 1)
        # softmax
        attention = F.softmax(attention, dim=-1)
        # [batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, D]
        X = torch.matmul(attention, value)
        X = X.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        X = torch.cat(torch.split(X, batch_size_, dim=0), dim=-1)  # orginal K, change to batch_size
        X = self.FC(X)
        del query, key, value, attention
        return X


class gatedFusion(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self, D, bn_decay):
        super(gatedFusion, self).__init__()
        self.FC_xs = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=None,
                        bn_decay=bn_decay, use_bias=False)
        self.FC_xt = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=None,
                        bn_decay=bn_decay, use_bias=True)
        self.FC_h = FC(input_dims=[D, D], units=[D, D], activations=[F.relu, None],
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)

    def forward(self, HS, HT):
        HS = HS.to(device)
        HT = HT.to(device)

        XS = self.FC_xs(HS)
        XT = self.FC_xt(HT)
        z = torch.sigmoid(torch.add(XS, XT))
        H = torch.add(torch.mul(z, HS), torch.mul(1 - z, HT))
        H = self.FC_h(H)
        del XS, XT, z
        return H


class STAttBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, K, d, bn_decay, mask=False):
        super(STAttBlock, self).__init__()
        self.spatialAttention = spatialAttention(K, d, bn_decay)
        self.temporalAttention = temporalAttention(K, d, bn_decay, mask=mask)
        self.gatedFusion = gatedFusion(K * d, bn_decay)

    def forward(self, X, STE):
        X = X.to(device)
        STE = STE.to(device)
        HS = self.spatialAttention(X, STE)
        HT = self.temporalAttention(X, STE)
        H = self.gatedFusion(HS, HT)
        del HS, HT
        return torch.add(X, H)


class transformAttention(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self, K, d, bn_decay):
        super(transformAttention, self).__init__()
        D = K * d
        self.K = K
        self.d = d
        self.FC_q = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_k = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_v = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC = FC(input_dims=D, units=D, activations=F.relu,
                     bn_decay=bn_decay)

    def forward(self, X, STE_his, STE_pred):
        X = X.to(device)
        STE_his = STE_his.to(device)
        STE_pred = STE_pred.to(device)
        batch_size = X.shape[0]
        # [batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, K * d]
        query = self.FC_q(STE_pred)
        key = self.FC_k(STE_his)
        value = self.FC_v(X)
        # [K * batch_size, num_step, num_vertex, d]
        query = torch.cat(torch.split(query, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        key = torch.cat(torch.split(key, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        value = torch.cat(torch.split(value, self.K, dim=-1), dim=0)
        # query: [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_pred, d]
        # key:   [K * batch_size, num_vertex, d, num_his]
        # value: [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_his, d]
        query = query.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        key = key.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
        value = value.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        # [K * batch_size, num_vertex, num_pred, num_his]
        attention = torch.matmul(query, key)
        attention /= (self.d ** 0.5)
        attention = F.softmax(attention, dim=-1)
        # [batch_size, num_pred, num_vertex, D]
        X = torch.matmul(attention, value)
        X = X.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        X = torch.cat(torch.split(X, batch_size, dim=0), dim=-1)
        X = self.FC(X)
        del query, key, value, attention
        return X


class GMAN(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self, SE, args, bn_decay):
        super(GMAN, self).__init__()
        L = args.L
        K = args.K
        d = args.d
        D = K * d
        self.num_his = args.num_his
        self.SE = SE.to(device)
        self.STEmbedding = STEmbedding(D, bn_decay)
        self.STAttBlock_1 = nn.ModuleList([STAttBlock(K, d, bn_decay) for _ in range(L)])
        self.STAttBlock_2 = nn.ModuleList([STAttBlock(K, d, bn_decay) for _ in range(L)])
        self.transformAttention = transformAttention(K, d, bn_decay)
        self.FC_1 = FC(input_dims=[1, D], units=[D, D], activations=[F.relu, None],
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)
        self.FC_2 = FC(input_dims=[D, D], units=[D, 1], activations=[F.relu, None],
                       bn_decay=bn_decay)

    def forward(self, X, TE):
        X = X.to(device)
        TE = TE.to(device)
        # input
        X = torch.unsqueeze(X, -1)
        X = self.FC_1(X)
        # STE
        STE = self.STEmbedding(self.SE, TE)
        STE_his = STE[:, :self.num_his]
        STE_pred = STE[:, self.num_his:]
        # encoder
        for net in self.STAttBlock_1:
            X = net(X, STE_his)
        # transAtt
        X = self.transformAttention(X, STE_his, STE_pred)
        # decoder
        for net in self.STAttBlock_2:
            X = net(X, STE_pred)
        # output
        X = self.FC_2(X)
        del STE, STE_his, STE_pred
        return torch.squeeze(X, 3)



Test.py:
import torch
import time
import math
import numpy as np
from utils.utils_ import log_string, metric
from utils.utils_ import load_data



def test(args, log, device):
    (trainX, trainTE, trainY, valX, valTE, valY, testX, testTE,
     testY, SE, mean, std) = load_data(args)
    num_train, _, num_vertex = trainX.shape
    num_val = valX.shape[0]
    num_test = testX.shape[0]
    train_num_batch = math.ceil(num_train / args.batch_size)
    val_num_batch = math.ceil(num_val / args.batch_size)
    test_num_batch = math.ceil(num_test / args.batch_size)

    # GPU Util
    trainX = trainX.to(device)
    trainTE = trainTE.to(device)
    trainY = trainY.to(device)
    valX = valX.to(device)
    valTE = valTE.to(device)
    valY = valY.to(device)
    testX = testX.to(device)
    testTE = testTE.to(device)
    testY = testY.to(device)
    SE = SE.to(device)
    #mean = mean.to(device)
    #std = std.to(device)

    model = torch.load(args.model_file)
    #GPU util
    model.to(device)
    

    # test model
    log_string(log, '**** testing model ****')
    log_string(log, 'loading model from %s' % args.model_file)
    model = torch.load(args.model_file)
    log_string(log, 'model restored!')
    log_string(log, 'evaluating...')

    with torch.no_grad():

        trainPred = []
        for batch_idx in range(train_num_batch):
            start_idx = batch_idx * args.batch_size
            end_idx = min(num_train, (batch_idx + 1) * args.batch_size)
            X = trainX[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            TE = trainTE[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            pred_batch = model(X, TE)
            trainPred.append(pred_batch.detach().clone())
            del X, TE, pred_batch
        trainPred = [tp.detach().cpu().numpy() for tp in trainPred]
        trainPred = torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(trainPred, axis=0)).to(device)
        trainPred = trainPred * std + mean

        valPred = []
        for batch_idx in range(val_num_batch):
            start_idx = batch_idx * args.batch_size
            end_idx = min(num_val, (batch_idx + 1) * args.batch_size)
            X = valX[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            TE = valTE[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            pred_batch = model(X, TE)
            valPred.append(pred_batch.detach().clone())
            del X, TE, pred_batch
        valPred = [vp.detach().cpu().numpy() for vp in valPred]
        valPred = torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(valPred, axis=0)).to(device)
        valPred = valPred * std + mean

        testPred = []
        start_test = time.time()
        for batch_idx in range(test_num_batch):
            start_idx = batch_idx * args.batch_size
            end_idx = min(num_test, (batch_idx + 1) * args.batch_size)
            X = testX[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            TE = testTE[start_idx: end_idx].to(device)
            pred_batch = model(X, TE)
            testPred.append(pred_batch.detach().clone())
            del X, TE, pred_batch
        testPred = [tp.detach().cpu().numpy() for tp in testPred]
        testPred = torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(testPred, axis=0)).to(device)
        testPred = testPred* std + mean
    end_test = time.time()
    train_mae, train_rmse, train_mape = metric(trainPred, trainY)
    val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape = metric(valPred, valY)
    test_mae, test_rmse, test_mape = metric(testPred, testY)
    log_string(log, 'testing time: %.1fs' % (end_test - start_test))
    log_string(log, '                MAE\t\tRMSE\t\tMAPE')
    log_string(log, 'train            %.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f%%' %
               (train_mae, train_rmse, train_mape * 100))
    log_string(log, 'val              %.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f%%' %
               (val_mae, val_rmse, val_mape * 100))
    log_string(log, 'test             %.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f%%' %
               (test_mae, test_rmse, test_mape * 100))
    log_string(log, 'performance in each prediction step')
    MAE, RMSE, MAPE = [], [], []
    
    for step in range(args.num_pred):
        mae, rmse, mape = metric(testPred[:, step], testY[:, step])
        MAE.append(mae)
        RMSE.append(rmse)
        MAPE.append(mape)
        log_string(log, 'step: %02d         %.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f%%' %
                   (step + 1, mae, rmse, mape * 100))
    average_mae = torch.mean(torch.stack(MAE))
    average_rmse = torch.mean(torch.stack(RMSE))
    average_mape = torch.mean(torch.stack(MAPE))
    log_string(
        log, 'average:         %.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f%%' %
             (average_mae, average_rmse, average_mape * 100))
    return trainPred, valPred, testPred



Add full stacktrace if possible. Check if SE is on GPU, AFAIK it seem to be the only thing that mess with the input device in the forward pass. If you want SE to be recognized and managed by module, consider register it as a buffer (with persistent=False if you don't want it in the state_dict.

I updated the question and followed your advice, however, I still have that problem @MinhNH

Try to put valY = valY.to(valPred.device) before you use it in the train function. I do see you comment it out.
